# ADO.Net entity framework SQL loginPermissions

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, ado.net

I am fairly new to entity framework, and i am planning to use it in my next project.

what permissions should web give to the sql server user login which entity framework uses?
since i read entity framework does DML operations do i need to provide  datawriter role to login?

Answer (score 0):

To login, no, you won't need datawriter (for the EF connection; the membership provider's connection will need it if you use the SQL provider). But if you expect to insert/update/delete data with the EF, then yes, you'll need that.